# How to send a gif with an inline keyboard when start is pressed using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a menu bot. All is working but I can't put a GIF for decoration before the keyboard and message.

I used some variations of `.inputmedia` and `.document`
from [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable).

I know nothing and have zero python knowledge. I can only understand on the fly from reading on the internet. I really can't understand how to phrase it.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
import emoji
def start(bot, update):
  update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
                            reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def main_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=main_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def first_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=first_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())
```

pretty much all i need is an example how to phrase a `inputgif` command with some text and a markup keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did my answer solved your problem? if so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[image]

If *yes*, read on! If *no*, tell me in the comments.

- We're gonna use the `send_animation` method from [telegram.Bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=gif#telegram.Bot.send_animation) class.

  > Use this method to send animation files (GIF or H.264/MPEG-4 AVC video without sound).
- We'll need to know the `file_id` of the GIF that we wish to send! **Important**: We need to get the `file_id` in [the same chat with the bot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493482/6282576)!

Here's how we can send a GIF with a `caption` and an `inline keyboard` (you can see the full code on my GitHub: [wehavetogoback.py](https://github.com/amirashabani/python-examples/blob/master/wehavetogoback.py))

```
keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton('yes ', callback_data='yes'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('no ', callback_data='no')
    ]
]

bot.send_animation(
    chat_id=update.message.chat.id,
    animation='file_id',
    caption='go back??',
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use these methods:

- `update.message.send_animation()`
- `bot.send_animation()`
- `bot.edit_message_media()`

For example:

```
def start(bot, update):
    gif_link='https://media.giphy.com/media/yFQ0ywscgobJK/giphy.gif'
    update.message.reply_animation(
        animation=gif_link,
        caption=main_menu_message(),
        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard(),
        parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
    )
```

upd: @amir-a-shabani thank you for edition and thanks to @david-kha for using code examples)

Comment: you got it ^_^ one small thing; the last line of code needs 4 spaces before it! I tried to edit it again, but the community bot rejected it.

Comment: 2 spaces! my condolences to your teammates :))

Comment: thay use 2 spaces too) if you can see on @david code example, i think it is my work too)

Comment: I see, have fun coding 